# Can one take damage from getting shot in the hat?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In TF2, I usually wear smaller hats, especially as Sniper, to reduce my **visual** profile, so that I'm less likely to be **seen**.

But that leads me to another question: what if one is wearing a tall hat like **[Dr.'s Dapper Topper](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Dr%27s_Dapper_Topper)**?

[image: Dr.'s Dapper Topper]

Obviously, a soldier's head only physically occupies the bottom half of Dr.'s Dapper Topper, **so what happens when the top half is shot**?

Does the soldier take damage from any shot anywhere in the hat?

Do non-set hats have any effect on where or how a player can be hit?

Comment: I just have to say this is the best question name ever.

Comment: -1 for waah? weaksauce!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, [hats are not part of the hitbox](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/437678-team-fortress-2/53460720), in fact the hitbox for your head probably isn't quite where you think it is:

The head hitbox is actually quite a bit larger than the character's actual heads, take a peek at the hitbox renders:

Comment: +1 Great Answer.  The head hitbox is huge!  I'm a sad panda because my ego got reduced through this knowledge.   I kind of suspected that the hit box on the head was large, because I've got some point blank head shots that were waayy too easy.

Comment: @MarkRogers it can easily seem like hats are part of the hitbox because they fill in some of the space between the top of the visible model and the actual hitbox, which is always slightly to significantly taller than the actual model. Another fun fact; spy's hitboxes don't change when they're disguised!

Comment: So you can't make a hatshot? *ducks, runs*

Comment: One problem with this answer - it doesn't make it clear than bullets and projectiles use two entirely different sets of hitboxes.  Bullets use the one depicted in the second video, while projectiles (like huntsman arrows) use a single large hitbox that is the same for every class, which is why you have a larger margin of error for the arrow (arr'r?).  To put it another way: the head hitbox is huge, but only for the huntsman.  Sniper rifle hitboxes need to be more accurate.