# Does wearing hats make it harder for others to shoot you?

Tags: team-fortress-2

So I'm considering selling my anger because every last sniper in tf2 has one, and I don't want to look like everyone else...I thought about buying a cold killer, but then I realized I want a hat that helps me. So, any hats that make you harder to shoot, or that at least don't put a big target on your head? (not including unusuals)

Comment: [Hats don't affect your hitbox](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/102033/can-one-take-damage-from-getting-shot-in-the-hat/102035#102035)

Comment: I know, but they do make you easier/harder to see.

Comment: This entire premise is silly. If wearing a hat makes you an easier target, that's because they're so jealous of how good it looks on you that they get distracted and pull the trigger on you, thereby saving your Medic or other vital teammate from a certain death (or at least buying them some extra seconds for escape). Your hat is more valuable than your life, so you should always be proud of the hat you wear, even if it costs you your life.

Comment: inspiring talk by the pyro...good point

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use the [Master's yellow belt](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Master%27s_Yellow_Belt) (painted **black**, of course) or [other small hats](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Ritzy_Rick%27s_Hair_Fixative).
[image]

The other larger hats may throw off some noob snipers, but I prefer to minimize my visual profile to avoid being seen as much as possible.  Sometimes large hats can be seen over a fence or other obstruction when the sniper would normally remain unseen.  The snipers nest area in [hightower](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Hightower), for instance, has a fence leading up to the stairs that would allow a large hat to be visible behind.

Sniper battles are ideally won by attacking from an unexpected direction.
[image]
[image]

Comment: interesting, could you post a pic of your black belt?

Comment: @Jimmt - Sure, this is how I usually load out.

Comment: Why can't I see the huge quiver of arrows which are visible above your head? ;)

Comment: +1 for black belt in jarate, I've had it on my sniper for probably years now

Comment: @DavidYell -  Wearing a smaller hat still reduces the chance that one will be seen.

Answer (score 4):

[Ritzy Rick's Hair Fixative](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Ritzy_Rick%27s_Hair_Fixative)? (aka no hat)

[Towering Pillar of Hats](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Towering_Pillar_of_Hats) is obviously very conspicuous, but maybe people will try shooting the top of the hat and miss?

In reality it's going to make very, very little difference.

Comment: So you pay $5 to not have a hat at all? Well played, Valve, well played.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be an anti-sniper, you could consider using the [Croc-o-Style Kit](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Croc-o-Style_Kit). Equipping the ol' snaggletooth hat along with the sydney sleeper, danger shield, and bushwacka, makes it so you cannot be killed by headshots. Out of any hats out there, this one by far gives you the most "utility".

It also looks awesome as a set.

Comment: Now valve sucks and the item sets are gone

Answer (score 0):

I would Recommend the cold killer and some kind of veal. Not only does it Look good but its also a small hat. But at the end of the day, No hat is really gonna help.
Don't think this helped much but hope it helped :D
And if you want to be a anti sniper Sniper then use Darwins danger shield

Comment: I don't play much TF2, but I don't think this really addresses the question.